# NamedJdbcParameterTemplate : -418 SQL error with setting Date

Tags: java, sql, spring, db2

I have below code in my java class:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

parameters.addValue("myDate", new java.sql.Date(this.sdf.parse(this.myDate).getTime()));
// this also not working : parameters.addValue("myDate", this.myDate);

SqlRowSet rs = namedParamJdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(this.my_sql, parameters);
```

Where the sql is:

```
SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTAB WHERE DATE(:myDate) < '2014-07-26'
```

The code is failing with error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTAB WHERE DATE(?) < '2014-07-26']; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.nm: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.50.152
```

`-418` error says : The statement cannot be executed because a parameter marker has been used in an invalid way.

What is the issue ?
What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `DATE(:myDate)` to `CAST(:myDate AS DATE)`. Sometimes DB2 is very peculiar about having "untyped" parameters (even when you're explicitly casting it here with the `DATE` function).

Have a look at this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382197/458501) I have on `-418`.

Comment: yes... don't know why but DATE(:myDate) is not working but CAST(:myDate as DATE) is working!