# org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Tags: java, sql, db2, jdbctemplate

```
StringBuilder myquery = new StringBuilder();

  myquery.append("SELECT * from Student stu")
  .append(" WHERE stu.Roll IN ( '120', '140') AND stuv2.Roll is null ")
  .append(" AND date(stu.admission) between ")
  .append("timestamp(").append("?").append(")").append(" AND  CURRENT DATE- 30 DAY");

 final Object[] args = new Object[] {
        getAdm() 
    } ; //its returning '2020-10-01 03:00:00'
    int[] types = new int[] { Types.CHAR  };
    List<Students> result = null;  
    result = jdbcTemplate.query(myquery, args, types, new Mapper());
```

Incorrect query is being built, I am expecting value from args to replace the "?" :

```
 SELECT * from Student stu WHERE stu.Roll IN ( '120', '140') AND stuv2.Roll is null 
 AND date(stu.admission) between timestamp(?) AND CURRENT DATE-100 DAY
```

I am getting the following error :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.66

nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.66
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1444) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:706) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:758) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at com.optum.chy.component.DB2Service.selectData(DB2Service.java:278) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: You have `query` and `myquery`. Correct your code sample

Comment: `stuv2.Roll`, probably should be `stuv.Roll`.

Comment: `CURRENT DATE` => `CURRENT_DATE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error it seems like the argument is not recognized or not as a date at least ...

Try casting your argument as a date `CAST( "parameter_here" AS DATE)`

Also, I'd rather use `MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();` , but that's  different subject

Edit bis :  jarlh pointed out and corrected mistakes in your query, you have some typos you should fix.

You can look into this thread , which is similar : [NamedJdbcParameterTemplate : -418 SQL error with setting Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734378/namedjdbcparametertemplate-418-sql-error-with-setting-date)

Comment: updated my answer, i don't know if you checked the comments that jarlh left you