# DB2 SQL - Unresolved Untyped Expression Error with PreparedStatement

Tags: sql, db2, prepared-statement

I am having a weird error when dealing with a PreparedStatement.

This is the query that works in Squirrel SQL:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, MAX(TRANSACTION_COUNT) as UNIT_COUNT, '2018-05-20' as EVENT_DATE, 'XYZ File Transfer' as TYPE, 'Financial Report' as EVENT 
FROM  REPORT_TABLE RT  
WHERE upper(REPORT_STATUS) = 'READY' and TRUNC(CREATED_TS) = '2018-05-20' and TRANSACTION_COUNT > 0 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

This is my PreparedStatement:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, MAX(TRANSACTION_COUNT) as UNIT_COUNT, :date as EVENT_DATE, 'XYZ File Transfer' as TYPE, 'Financial Report' as EVENT 
FROM  REPORT_TABLE RT  
WHERE upper(REPORT_STATUS) = 'READY' and TRUNC(CREATED_TS) = :date and TRANSACTION_COUNT > 0 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

The parameter is being set by:

params.addValue("date", "2018-05-20");

When I run it as a PreparedStatement, I get this error message:

```
nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, S    QLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=unresolved untyped expression, DRIVER=4.19.66
```

I tried looking at some IBM resources regarding the error message, but nothing is relevant to my issue at hand.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: `params.addValue("timestamp", "2018-05-2018");`

Comment: Whoops, fat finger on my part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve SQL0418N Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381898/how-to-resolve-sql0418n-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CAST or DATE()  to tell the compiler the expected type, example:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, MAX(TRANSACTION_COUNT) as UNIT_COUNT, DATE(:date) as EVENT_DATE, 'XYZ File Transfer' as TYPE, 'Financial Report' as EVENT 
FROM  REPORT_TABLE RT  
WHERE upper(REPORT_STATUS) = 'READY' and TRUNC(CREATED_TS) = CAST(:date as DATE) and TRANSACTION_COUNT > 0 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```